# C only reads first struct, cannot read other inputs

Tags: c

I'm creating a basic grocery delivery system. The code is working properly if you input for the first time. However, if you input another ID, in the receipt part, it just prints "no delivery pending" despite putting the required information.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct grocery {
    int number;
    char prod1[20];//products
    char prod2[20];
    char prod3[20];
    char prod4[20];
    float price1; //price of product
    float price2; 
    float price3; 
    float price4; 
    char status; //status of products
    float ttl; //total
};
struct grocery g;
FILE * fptr;
char prod[][20] = {"tissue","soap","shampoo","lotion","tampons"};
float price[5] = {1.00, 2.30, 1.50, 4.30, 5.00};
int orders(int id, int g1, int g2, int g3, int g4) {
    int a;
    fptr = fopen("delivery.txt", "a");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        fptr = fopen("delivery.txt", "w");
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    g.number = id;
    fflush(stdin);
    //copies file 
    strcpy(g.prod1, prod[g1 - 1]);
    strcpy(g.prod2, prod[g2 - 1]);
    strcpy(g.prod3, prod[g3 - 1]);
    strcpy(g.prod4, prod[g4 - 1]);
    g.price1 = price[g1 - 1];
    g.price2 = price[g2 - 1];
    g.price3 = price[g3 - 1];
    g.price4 = price[g4 - 1];
    g.status = 'd'; //status is set to 'being delivered(d)'
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    fwrite(&g, sizeof(struct grocery), 1, fptr);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\n\n\tyour items are being delivered\n\n\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 1;
}
void receipt(int id) {
    float total, mon, change; //mon -> money given by user
    int c = 0;
    fptr = fopen("delivery.txt", "r+");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("error opening file\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while (fread(&g, sizeof(struct grocery), 1, fptr) == 1) {
        if (g.number == id) {
            printf("\tdelivery total: \n");
            printf("\t%s\t%20.2f\n", g.prod1, g.price1);
            printf("\t%s\t%20.2f\n", g.prod2, g.price2);
            printf("\t%s\t%20.2f\n", g.prod3, g.price3);
            printf("\t%s\t%20.2f\n", g.prod4, g.price4);
            total = g.price1 + g.price2 + g.price3;
            g.ttl = total;
            printf("\t-----------------------------\n");
            printf("\ttotal                   $%.2f\n", total);
            do {
                printf("\tcash :               $");
                scanf("%f", &mon);
                if (mon < total) {
                    c = 0;
                    printf("\n\t insufficient amount...try again\n\n");
                }
                else {
                    g.status = 'r'; //changes status to "received"
                    c = 1;
                    change = mon - total;
                    printf("\tchange:       $%.2f\n", change);
                }

        } while (c == 0); 
        }
        else {
            printf("no delivery pending. \n\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int id, a, b, c, d; //a,b,c,d are the items the user wants to buy
    int e = 0; 
    printf("enter USER ID to continue... ");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    printf("ITEMS LIST: \n");
    printf("1 - tissue\n 2 - soap \n 3 - shampoo \n 4 - lotion \n 5 - tampons \n");
    printf("enter item codes: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    e = orders(id, a, b, c, d);
    if (e == 1)
        receipt(id);
}
```

I can type any ID and it prints the receipt just fine but I try another one it just goes to the else statement.

Comment: How do you input another ID in the receipt part? There is no input for another ID in the receipt part.

Comment: @user253751 Oops, I meant to add a comma there. I meant if you do the same process again it just keeps going to else. Like if the external file already has text.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour

Comment: @LeilaK. Well the computer is doing what you told it - have you tried following it along yourself to see what it's doing? For example, it reads an entry from the file, and if that entry matches then it prints the stuff, and if it doesn't match then it says so and exits the program. It never gets around to the second entry if the first one doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `orders()` function is appending records to the `delivery.txt` file, then the `receipt()` function reads the *first* record and checks that the record id matches the passed id. If it matches it continues, but otherwise it exits with `"no delivery pending"`.

If you want the `receipt()` function to look at further records, then you need something like:

```c
void receipt(int id) {
    float total, mon, change; //mon -> money given by user
    int c = 0;
    fptr = fopen("delivery.txt", "r+");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("error opening file\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int found = 0;
    while (fread(&g, sizeof(struct grocery), 1, fptr) == 1) {
        if (g.number == id) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        printf("\tdelivery total: \n");
        printf("\t%s\t%20.2f\n", g.prod1, g.price1);
        printf("\t%s\t%20.2f\n", g.prod2, g.price2);
        printf("\t%s\t%20.2f\n", g.prod3, g.price3);
        printf("\t%s\t%20.2f\n", g.prod4, g.price4);
        total = g.price1 + g.price2 + g.price3;
        g.ttl = total;
        printf("\t-----------------------------\n");
        printf("\ttotal                   $%.2f\n", total);
        do {
            printf("\tcash :               $");
            scanf("%f", &mon);
            if (mon < total) {
                c = 0;
                printf("\n\t insufficient amount...try again\n\n");
            }
            else {
                g.status = 'r'; //changes status to "received"
                c = 1;
                change = mon - total;
                printf("\tchange:       $%.2f\n", change);
            }

        } while (c == 0); 
    } else {
        printf("no delivery pending. \n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

(please note that the code seems to have also other problems besides this).

Comment: yes, but if you input id for the first time it works fine. Thereafter, If you do it again(enter another ID), it just keeps defaulting to "no delivery pending"

Comment: @LeilaK. if you input the id of the _first_ record it works, if you input a different id the `receipt()` code doesn't search for the record but just says `"no delivery pending"`. If you want it to perform the search across all records, you have to move the `else` branch contents outside the `while` loop (and use a "found" variable).

Comment: wow. I've been trying to fix this for hours. Thanks for helping out!